# retrive all picture relative to a news in another table from a db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My structure:

### news:

```
id
data
titolo
testo
```

### newsFoto:

```
id
idParent (news id)
titolo
fotoName
```

I would like to have all news listed and, if there are some with pictures, with them.

To be more clear:

Every news listed with in all pictures for every news, not duplicated news records to show all pictures

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is SQL Fiddle with your solution:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b616d/1

Actual Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT news.data, news.didolo, news.testo, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fotoname) 
                                                     FROM newsfoto 
                                                     WHERE newsfoto.idparent = news.id) as photo
FROM news
LEFT JOIN newsfoto
ON news.id = newsfoto.idparent
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes thanks, but now i have repeated news records for all picture, so i added: group by news.id but then i have only one for picture for every news

Comment: You cannot have both your "requirements" unless you are starting that all pictures need to be flattened to a concatenated string or something. Perhpas you can add an example of your desired out put especially for the case of multiple pictures?  News will always repeat by the number of records there are in newsfotos unless you use an aggregation or concatenation method

Comment: for example output shoul look like this: news1 bla bla (foto1,foto2,foto3) news2 bla bla (foto1,foto2) and so on...

Comment: Check out GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: SELECT news.id, news.data, news.titolo, news.testo, news.allegato, newsFoto.idParent, newsFoto.titolo as fotoTitolo, newsFoto.foto, newsFoto.id as fotoId, GROUP_CONCAT(newsFoto.id)
FROM news 
LEFT JOIN newsFoto 
ON news.id = newsFoto.idParent 
group by news.id
ORDER BY news.data DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: thnks it do the trick, now i have to show all pictures that i retrive in the column (concat) for example 1,jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg can you give me a tip on php code to  use

Comment: You can put it in array when u get it from database then u can explode that array into parts and use img1 where you want img2 where you want and so on. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I am Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

A query similar to this one should work:

```
select * from news as n
left outer join newsFoto as nf
on nf.idParent = n.id;
```